# Angular Clear form control errors

Tags: angular, angular-validation

How to clear the errors on form control. I have a method that tries to clear the errors on the form control but in vain.

`this.form.controls[ 'postalCode' ].setErrors(null);`

The form control name is postalCode and when I set the error to null, it doesn't remove the error from that control.

Comment: generally the errors are showed only if the control is invalid and touched, so the idea is markAsUntouched the FormControls: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markasuntouched (well you need loop over all the FormControls in your FormGroup)

Answer (score 2):

**To clear all the errors**

```
this.form.get('postalCode').setErrors(null);
```

**To clear by its key**

```
this.form.get('postalCode').setErrors({key: null});
this.form.get('postalCode').updateValueAndValidity(); //may need this in child components
```

Answer (score -1):

try doing
this.form.controls[ 'postalCode' ].setErrors({});